# How could my List lose its order?

Tags: java, sql, list, collections

For my Java application, I make a PL/SQL database query that fills out a List object in a particular order.  When I run this query in PL/SQL, the List is always in the correct order, and when I check the results of filling out this List, it always shows that the List is correctly organized.

However, when that data appears on our app, and is supposed to be in that same order, two items on that List will sometimes be in the incorrect order.

In the example I am testing, there are 6 items in the List, and the two being ordered are in the middle.  None of the other items on the List lose their place.

Having examined the code throughly, I have determined that the exact moment the order of this list is lost is when it is added to a Collection object.  The relevant processes are shown below

What might be happening to my List object in transit to the Collection that could make it lose its order?

Code Example:

```
Collection results = null;
results = new TreeSet(new TransactionComparator(rd.getDescendingOrder()));
Collection c = cleanClass.getList(); // Creates a list of ordered items
results.addAll(c);
```

Comment: how sure are you that your query order and this TransactionComparator always produce the same order?

Comment: @radai The transaction comparator could be the problem, now that you mention it. I will take a closer look at it, but I am very confident in the query - not once in dozens of tests has it failed to produce the correct order, even when the end result is faulty.

Comment: A [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) has it's own ordering (it *doesn't matter* that this being accessed through the Collection interface). The source ordering is largely irrelevant.

Comment: If you want to keep the date in the same order in which you retrieve from the database, why not just add all items to an ArrayList?

Comment: @andreban That sounds like a reasonable solution.  If nothing else turns up in my investigation, I'll consider it.  It would certainly be cleaner than the code we have right now.

Comment: It did turn out that the TransactionComparator needed some additional modification, but it also turned out that without properly fixing the queries that were being run, this would never have worked!  Now...I am in a bind, because I dont' think there's any way to answer this except "It was the TransactionComparator".

Comment: @Zibbobz You're welcome to add that as an answer and accept it, and also flag your question as typo/unreproducible as the answer won't be helpful to other readers.